# Can "for" relations in a laravel seeder use the child model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-factory

I'm writing a seeder in which one model (`ProductVariant`) belongs to (many to one) other model (`Product`). For properly seeding all relations on the `Product`, I need to access the `ProductVariant` model. The Laravel documentation shows this is possible with the `->has()` function, but because of the nature of this relationship I need to use a `->for()`, which doesn't seem to work in the same way.

Below is the snipped of code I'm talking about and how I would expect it to work:

```php
ProductVariant::factory()
    ->for(
        Product::factory()
            ->state(function (array $attributes, ProductVariant $productVariant) {
                dd(($attributes, $productVariant);
            })
    )->create();
```

Is there another way to do what I need it to do or am I missing something?

Documentation I'm referring to: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing#has-many-relationships

Comment: Its impossible to make "child" before "parent". Why not reverse it? Will throw an error?

Comment: @Localhousee the relationship structure is a bit more complicated but irrelevant for this question; The rest of my relations demand I create the `ProductVariant` before the `Product`. In factories it's completely possible to create a child before a parent as long as you provide the parent in the same factory function (through ->has() or ->for()). This code runs fine, only problem is that `Product` can't get some values from higher up the relationship chain.

Comment: higher up the relationship chain, offcourse since it is not created. I feel like you are leaving key reasons for this, by not including why you want to create the child before the parent. For right now it is hard to help.